# UINavigationController's back button doesn't disappear when UIViewController is popped

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have this UINavigationController that when pushed automatically goes to landscape but can be changeable.

When I pop the view in portrait it goes back to the first/root view normally but when I pop the view in landscape, the back button remains and when I press it, it animates just like when popping a normal navigation controller and the button disappears.

I tried logging the view controllers whenever the main view appears and same with the second view, the logs that I got we're quite normal. On the first view only 1 view controller, and on the pushed view only 2 view controllers.

So, what could be the problem?

I'm not adding any custom buttons at all. It's the standard UINavigationController's back button.

Code:

### Pushing the view controller

```
SomeViewController *rmVC = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil];

AppDelegate *ad = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[ad.someNavigationController pushViewController: rmVC animated:YES];
```

This was done in this way 'cause this was pushed in a presentModalViewController

### At someViewController's viewDidLoad

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

### Pics

http://s1058.photobucket.com/albums/t411/shlbypuerto/

Comment: you are adding that back button from code?

Comment: I didn't add any custom back button it's the navigationcontroller's

Comment: @Jessedc I've added some codes here.

Comment: Could you have maybe pushed the same view controller twice?

I recall back then, I had a view controller respond to a certain notification, now when I had two of the view controller on the navigation stack, both copies of the view controller responded to the notification and as a result, they both pushed a copy of a view controller. Pressing the back button looked like it didn't do anything.

Comment: @Zhang but when it's on portrait the button disappears. and when I log the viewcontrollers there are only 2 view controllers. 
with what happened to you, did it have 3 view controllers? was the copy present also?

Comment: In all honesty, I've edited your post and still can't completely visualise the issue. If you provide some images, or more complete code examples I'm sure I can help.

Comment: @Jessedc I've added images. the fourth one is the first going left. Or the one with the button is the first one.